# Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org

Tags: errors

All the pages in my wordpress site shows the following warning. (both in admin view, and the site)

```
Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxx/wp-includes/update.php on line 295

Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxx/wp-includes/update.php on line 457
```

I tried replacing the update.php file and later the whole wp-includes and wp-admin directories. Still this error persists. Could it be a database issue? or an issue with any other file?

Comment: I did. Found similar posts but none of the solutions did work for me

Comment: In my case it occurs only due to a slow internet connection.

Comment: Sometimes because slow server , happened to me before and it was a server proplem

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? If so, you can add proxy settings to your **wp-config.php** file so that your site can properly access **WordPress.org** - http://wpengineer.com/1227/wordpress-proxysupport/.